# Representing percentage amounts for rate calculations in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working with a few financial formulas that involve float's and rates in percentages, and i'm having a little bit of problems trying to represent these values in my PHP code. Should i use BC Math? Should i divide all my percentages by 100? How would you represent the following formulas in PHP?

e.g: Amount has a tax amount of 8% and an interest rate of 1% a day. Given i want to borrow X amount and pay in 15 days, divided in 3 installments, how much per installment and total payback?

```
totalTax = amount * 0.08
totalAmount = (amount + totalTax)
interest = totalAmount * 0.01 * 15
perInstallment = totalAmount + totalInterest / 3
```

Comment: is the code that you posted not working? Are there any error messages that you are getting with this code ?

Answer (score 1):

The crucial PHP function is [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format). I'm also casting the type to (float) inside my custom function. As always, test this code. I'm curious if you find any edge cases where this math doesn't sync up with your financial calculations. It passed my tests...

```
function formatCurrency($input){
    $result = number_format((float)$input, 2, '.', ',');
    return $result;
}

$amount = 6458.56;
$totalTax = $amount * 0.08;
$totalAmount = $amount + $totalTax;
$interest = $totalAmount * 0.01 * 15;
$perInstallment = ($totalAmount + $interest) / 3;

echo 'Principal = $'.formatCurrency($amount).'<br/>';
echo 'Total Tax = $'.formatCurrency($totalTax).'<br/>';
echo 'Total Amount = $'.formatCurrency($totalAmount).'<br/>';
echo 'Total Interest = $'.formatCurrency($interest).'<br/>';
echo 'Each Installment = $'.formatCurrency($perInstallment).'<br/>';
```

Comment: can money_format function be used here to format the money ?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php ?

Comment: money_format is slightly sketchy in that is doesn't work on Windows servers. From the docs: The function money_format() is only defined if the system has strfmon capabilities. For example, Windows does not, so money_format() is undefined in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Attention with your financial operations: 15 days with 1% a day 
is **not** 15% but 16.1 %. Better use pow() function instead of multiply operator.

In PHP (run in command line, for example):

```
<?
$amount         = 1000.0 ;
$tax            = 1.08 ;  // 8%
$interestPerDay = 1.01 ;  // 1%/day
$days           = 15 ;

$totalAmount    = ($amount * $tax);
$totalAmountWithInterest = $totalAmount * pow($interestPerDay, $days) ;
$perInstallment = $totalAmountWithInterest / 3;

printf("Initial amout:   %.2f\n", $amount);
printf("Amount tax inc.: %.2f\n", $totalAmount);
printf("Total amount:    %.2f\n", $totalAmountWithInterest);
printf("Total interest:  %.2f\n", $totalAmountWithInterest - $amount);
printf("Per installment: %.2f\n", $perInstallment );
```

Gives:

```
Initial amout:   1000.00
Amount tax inc.: 1080.00
Total amount:    1253.85
Total interest:  253.85
Per installment: 417.95
```

According to @larsAnders, it now needs currency conversion.

Comment: What if i use cents instead of floats? What the change in the formula?

Comment: You can use cents for the initial amount if you wish. However, if your need is to avoid floats, the pow() function won't be of any use. You'll have to compute daily growth recursively caring operation order: `$amount_tomorrow = $amount_today * 101 / 100;` or, the same: `$a = $a + $a * 1 / 100;`. Does that helps enough ?